# Remove the style for all the rows in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My kendo grid is rendered as

```
              <tr class="k-master-row" data-uid="e232f2a2-7a9c-496b-bf78-bf56902c11a5" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

all rows are rendered with the same style. How to remove the above style for all rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added this in onDataBound event, it removed the style.

```
            $('tr').removeAttr('style');
```